# bash script creating a newline character?

Tags: xml, bash, awk, sed, grep

Hi I have a script to read 4.29.0 and convert to 4-29-0

The raw file I am reading is this:

```
$ cat package.xml  | grep version
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <version>4.29.0</version>
```

The command I have to read is this:

```
VERSION=$(grep "version" package.xml | awk -F '>|<' '{print $3}' | sed 's/\./-/g')
```

If I print it

```
echo "testing.. $VERSION"
```

This will print as follows

```
testing.. 
4-29-0
```

Why is there a new line character and how do I remoev this ? I want to see the string as

```
testing.. 4-29-0
```

Comment: What does `declare -p VERSION` or `printf '%s=%q\n' VERSION "$VERSION"` say?

Comment: (And why do you _expect_ your `grep | awk | sed` line to ignore the first line with the `<?xml` declaration?)

Comment: $ declare -p VERSION
declare -- VERSION="
4-29-0"

Comment: Do you have GNU awk? If you have `gensub` the whole pipeline could be collapsed down to one command.

Comment: `gawk -F'>|<' '/version/ && NR>1 { print gensub(/[.]/, "-", "g", $3); }'` -- no `grep` or `sed` needed. Certainly _could_ be done with a non-GNU awk too, but I have work to be doing.

Comment: (Also, using `awk` or `sed` or anything else that doesn't understand XML for this is a horrible idea; answers suggesting xmlstarlet, `xmllint --xpath`, etc. are _absolutely_ the way to go).

Comment: ...to give you an example of why `grep` should never be used for XML -- let's say part of your file is commented out with `<!--` and `-->`. A real XML parser will ignore everything in those comments, but `grep` doesn't know.

Comment: Similarly, a future version of your file can have `<foobar><version>4.29.0</version></foobar>` all one line without newlines; it's the exact same meaning to an XML parser, but the column numbers will be all wrong for `awk`, so that'll break.

Comment: There are a bunch of other XML constructs that grep/awk/etc don't understand -- CDATA elements, namespaces, etc etc etc; using them makes the larger system fragile, because people changing other components in ways that _should_ be perfectly valid will suddenly make the component you assembled break.

Comment: (Another example: In an XML document, someone could instead of writing the `.` character write `&#46;`, and a compliant parser will understand that to mean `.`; but, of course, `grep` and `sed` and `awk` are not compliant XML parsers, so they won't do that conversion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial **[grep](/questions/tagged/grep)** is **not sufficiently focused**.  You need to change

```
VERSION=$(grep "version" package.xml
```

to

```
VERSION=$(grep "<version>" package.xml
```

to ensure only the line that has the relevant content will be processed by the awk command.

Answer (score 2):

With `xmlstarlet`:

```
xmlstarlet edit --update '//version' -x 'translate(text(),".","-")' package.xml |
  xmlstarlet select --template --value-of '//version' -n
```

Output:

```
4-29-0
```

See: `xmlstarlet edit` and `xmlstarlet select`